# phonegap implement native menu for android

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to implement own native android menu with Phonegap 2.7. This solution worked on older version of phonegap(v2.2).

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    menu.add(Menu.NONE, 1, Menu.NONE, "menu 1");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, 2, Menu.NONE, "menu 2");
  return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Now I can't make it work. I need to use javascript event http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#menubutton.

Comment: what android target version are you using? The menu button is deprecated in the newer versions of android and to use the menu button your android:targetSdkVersion must be below 11. In general it is advised to implement you own menu button in the actionbar of the app, because as i said the menu button is deprecated.

Comment: I forgot to tell, you can check your targetSdkVersion in the AndroidManifest.xml - File in your Android Project.

Comment: I didn't know that. The targetSdkVersion is 17, so it is deprecated. Maybe I need to make own plugin which shows own kind of menu.